# Implemenation of Length N Moving average filter using block covolution algorithm(overlap and save algorithm)

Tags: convolution

I want to implement a Length N moving average filter using block convolution algorithm(overlap save algorithm)

I am copying block convolution algorithm(overlap save algorithm) from Proakis, DSP using MATLAB 3rd Ed

```
function [y] = ovrlpsav(x,h,N)
% Overlap-Save method of block convolution
% ----------------------------------------
% [y] = ovrlpsav(x,h,N)
% y = output sequence
% x = input sequence
% h = impulse response
% N = block length
%
Lenx = length(x); M = length(h);
M1 = M-1; L = N-M1;
h = [h zeros(1,N-M)];
%
x = [zeros(1,M1), x, zeros(1,N-1)]; % preappend (M-1) zeros
K = floor((Lenx+M1-1)/(L));         % # of blocks
Y = zeros(K+1,N);
% convolution with succesive blocks
for k=0:K
    xk = x(k*L+1:k*L+N);
    Y(k+1,:) = cconv(xk,h,N);
end

Y = Y(:,M:N)';                      % discard the first (M-1) samples
y = (Y(:))';                        % assemble output
```

Now using above function i am trying to implement a Length N moving average filter.
My script(m-file) is below

```
clc
clear all
close all
n=1:5
signal=n*pi;
subplot(221)
stem(n,signal);
xlabel('n');ylabel('amplitude');title('original signal')
noise=rand(1,5);
subplot(222)
stem(n,noise);
xlabel('n');ylabel('amplitude');title('noise signal');title('noise ')
p=ovrlpsav(signal,noise,6),
subplot(223)
stem(p);xlabel('n');ylabel('amplitude');title('corrupted signal')
m=5;
xu=0;
for i=1:m
    
    x=signal+noise;
    xu=xu+x;
end
xu=xu/m;
subplot(224)
stem(n,xu);xlabel('n');ylabel('amplitude');title('filtered signal')
```

I am getting a filtered signal similar to input signal as shown by above code,**but am i following proper approach?**

Comment: Why do you use `noise` as the impulse response in your call to the overlap-save function?

Comment: So i may corrupt original signal by convolving original signal with noise

Comment: But your title says that you're trying to implement a moving average using overlap-save. I don't see that in your code. And are you sure that you noise model should involve *convolving* a clean signal with noise?

Comment: here i am using overlap save: "p=ovrlpsav(signal,noise,6)"

Comment: "noise model should involve convolving a clean signal with noise"? No it isn't mandatory, but i think it this way. Can you please suggest any alternative?

Comment: I see that you used the overlap-save function, but I can't see where you used the impulse response of a moving average filter. As for the noise, the most common noise models use additive noise.

Comment: you mean"x=signal+noise" this expression should be used for creating noisy/corrupted signal??

Comment: That's at least what we often see in practice: additive noise.

Comment: impulse response of a moving average filter is a box function,where and how should i use that in my code?

Comment: Normally we use overlap-add to save computations.  Because the moving average filter has gains that are either constant or zero, there are algorithms for computing it (Google "CIC") that use far less computational resources than overlap-add.  Why do you want to use overlap-add here, instead of a more efficient method?

Comment: @TimWescott ,i just want to understand the efficiency of the method that i studied(overlap save)

Answer (score -1):

in psudo pyhon code

```
const tail = 5  

'inside loop where you feed it values

list.push(entry)
list.rotate.left(1)
if len(list)>tail list.pop()
avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
print avg
```

Comment: Please give answer in context of MATLAB code.Thanks

Comment: Oh i dont know matlab, it might be familiar, most coding languages allow for push and pop and shifting of lists